# improt Numba @jit meet warning message and @jit(nopython=True) will show error

Tags: python, for-loop, numba

I am a python newer.

I write some code try to mix pics to a new pic.

I finish it, but it wastes too much time.

so I try to use Numba let the code work on my gpu.
but meet some warning and error

> os Ubuntu 16
>
> pyhton version 3.5

```
for i in piclist:
img = cv2.imread(str(filepath)+'/'+str(i))
print (i)
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
bcolorlist.append(b)
gcolorlist.append(g)
rcolorlist.append(r)


@jit(nopython = True)
def select(bcolorlist,gcolorlist,rcolorlist):
    for i in range(len(bcolorlist)):
        b = bcolorlist[i].reshape(2073600,1)
        g = gcolorlist[i].reshape(2073600,1)
        r = rcolorlist[i].reshape(2073600,1)
        bcolorlist[i] = b
        gcolorlist[i] = g
        rcolorlist[i] = r
    bbb = np.concatenate(bcolorlist, axis=1)
    ggg = np.concatenate(gcolorlist, axis=1)
    rrr = np.concatenate(rcolorlist, axis=1)
    newb = []
    newg = []
    newr = []
    for line in bbb:
        newb.append(np.argmax(np.bincount(line)))
    newb = np.array(newb)
    for line in ggg:
        newg.append(np.argmax(np.bincount(line)))
    newg = np.array(newg)
    for line in rrr:
        newr.append(np.argmax(np.bincount(line)))
    newr = np.array(newr)
    return newb,newg,newr
```

that work normally without `@jit`

but with `@jit` will show below message

> test.py:61: NumbaWarning:
>   Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "select" failed type inference due to: Invalid use of Function() with argument(s) of type(s): (reflected list(array(uint8, 2d, C)), axis=Literalint)

Update the code now by suggestion

```
for f in files:
    if is_img((os.path.splitext(f)[1])):
         piclist.append(f)
start = time.time()
for i in piclist:
    img = cv2.imread(str(filepath)+'/'+str(i))
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
    bcolorlist.append(b)
    gcolorlist.append(g)
    rcolorlist.append(r)
bcolorlist = array(bcolorlist)
gcolorlist = array(gcolorlist)
rcolorlist = array(rcolorlist)

@jit(nopython = True)

def select(bcolorlist,gcolorlist,rcolorlist):
    r_res = np.zeros((len(bcolorlist), 2073600, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    g_res = np.zeros((len(gcolorlist), 2073600, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    b_res = np.zeros((len(rcolorlist), 2073600, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(bcolorlist)):
        r_res[i] = rcolorlist[i].reshape(2073600,1)
        g_res[i] = gcolorlist[i].reshape(2073600,1)
        b_res[i] = bcolorlist[i].reshape(2073600,1)
    r_res = r_res.reshape(2073600, len(rcolorlist))
    g_res = g_res.reshape(2073600, len(gcolorlist))
    b_res = b_res.reshape(2073600, len(bcolorlist))

    newr = np.zeros((2073600), dtype=np.uint8)
    newg = np.zeros((2073600), dtype=np.uint8)
    newb = np.zeros((2073600), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in range(b_res[:,0].size):
        newr[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(r_res[i,:]))
        newg[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(g_res[i,:]))
        newb[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(b_res[i,:]))

    return newb, newg, newr

b, g, r = select(bcolorlist,gcolorlist,rcolorlist)
newb = b.reshape(1920,1080)
newg = g.reshape(1920,1080)
newr = r.reshape(1920,1080)
img = cv2.merge([newb, newg, newr])
end = time.time()
print (end - start)
```

It's work normally!!!!

but it doesn't make the output image.....

Could I trouble you to give some advice?

Comment: how do your inputs look like?

Comment: Hi my input are as below
"       for i in piclist:
    img = cv2.imread(str(filepath)+'/'+str(i))
        b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
        bcolorlist.append(b)
        gcolorlist.append(g)
        rcolorlist.append(r)"

Comment: update my code, thanks for any reply.

Comment: haha ok I think my answer was sort of overcomplicated, now that I see what you want to do. Will post an update in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** - working example with rgb images as input. I didn't do image processing in Python in the past so this was a nice excursion. Some code below. Note that I added some input parameters to the function to make it more versatile. I also changed some variable names but that's just a matter of taste so don't worry.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def select(b, g, r, n, w, h): # added number of input images, width and height
    r_res = r.reshape(n, w*h) # flatten the images' rgb 2d arrays to 1d
    g_res = g.reshape(n, w*h)
    b_res = b.reshape(n, w*h)
    newr = np.zeros((w*h), dtype=np.uint8)
    newg = np.zeros((w*h), dtype=np.uint8)
    newb = np.zeros((w*h), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(w*h): # this is what takes time...
        newr[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(r_res[:,i]))
        newg[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(g_res[:,i]))
        newb[i] = np.argmax(np.bincount(b_res[:,i]))
    newb = newb.reshape(w,h) # reshape back from 1d to 2d
    newg = newg.reshape(w,h)
    newr = newr.reshape(w,h)
    return newb, newg, newr

imgs = ['D:/test/DSC02142.jpg', 'D:/test/DSC02606.jpg', 'D:/test/DSC01747.jpg']
bcolorlist, gcolorlist, rcolorlist = [], [], []
for i in imgs:
    b, g, r = cv2.split(cv2.imread(i))
    bcolorlist.append(b)
    gcolorlist.append(g)
    rcolorlist.append(r)

b = np.array(bcolorlist)
g = np.array(gcolorlist)
r = np.array(rcolorlist)

n, w, h = b.shape # assuming all images of equal width x height!
newb, newg, newr = select(b, g, r, n, w, h)

imgmerge = cv2.merge((newb, newg, newr))
cv2.imwrite('D:/test/output.jpg', imgmerge)
```

...produces weird stuff like this:
[image: merged_img]

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.
I had update my code. and i will try to use your code and reply ASAP.

Comment: Hi I update the code! it work in CUDA but Idon't see the output iamge...I am trying to debug. Could I  trouble you  to give some advice?

Comment: Made an update. Hope that works for you. My original code was a bit overcomplicated and not working in the desired way.

Comment: Hi sorry.....May I ask a question....
it works normally and fast than before...
but I use the "nvidia-smi" to check....this python code doesn't work in GPU...
Could I trouble you to give some advice?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!! I will try it myself. If not I will ask a new question~~~